# Convergence of sequence $a_0 := b$ and $a_{n+1} = 2^{a_n}$ in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fake-proofs, profinite-groups

I have a question about the convergence properties of a sequence in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$. It is part of an exercise is due to [this syllabus](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf). I got confused somewhere.

> Choose $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Let us define the sequence  $(a_n)_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: $$ a_0 \ := \  b,  \quad
>  \quad \text{ and } \quad \quad a_{n+1} \ := \ 2^{a_n} \ \text{ for } n
>  \geq 1 $$ The sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ can be seen as a
>    sequence on  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ as $$ \hat{a}_n \ := \ (a_n +
>  1!\mathbb{Z}, \ a_n + 2! \mathbb{Z}, \ a_n + 3!\mathbb{Z}, \dots )_n
>  \quad \quad \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}. $$ Show that
>
> - the sequence $(\hat{a}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  converges in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$
> - the limit $\hat{a}$ does not depend on the choice of $b$.

---

**My attempts**

As I silently suggested 
$
\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \ := \ \varprojlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
\ = \ \varprojlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z}.
$
The sequence $\hat{a}_n$ converges iff
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}
\quad \text{ such that } \quad
n \geq N \implies m! \ | \  a_n - a 
$$

I have no very little idea about what $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ could work.
I only know that $2^M \ | \ a_n$ for arbitrarily large $M$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. That means that $a$ has to divide $2$ as many times as $m!$ does. This is valid for any $m$, so $2^M \ | \ a$ for any $M \in \mathbb{Z}$.
That means that $a=0$ right? But $a_n$ can never become zero in for example $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, so I must be mistaking.

I know that usually we represent the sequence in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ as
$$
\left(
\sum_{0 \leq n \leq 0} a_n n! + 1!\mathbb{Z}, \
\sum_{0 \leq n \leq 1} a_n n! + 2!\mathbb{Z},  \
\sum_{0 \leq n \leq 2} a_n n! + 3!\mathbb{Z},  \
\dots
\right)
$$
But the choice of the representation should not matter right? What am I doing wrong?

---

I would like to have some help to see what I am doing wrong and to make a step to the solution of this exercise. Please do not give entire answers, at least not yet.

Comment: Why do you want to choose $a\in \mathbb Z$? This is certainly not possible. To show that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $\hat{\mathbb Z}$, it suffices to show that it is a Cauchy sequence (since $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ is complete).

Comment: @user218931, I certainly didn't want to choose $a$, I wanted to find it in fact.

Comment: Moreover, I already tried to prove the Cauchy property. I know what it means and I understand that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is complete, but I didn't manage the prove the Cauchy property. And even if I could it wouldn't be enough that the limit doesn't depend on $b$.

Comment: But using (and proving) the Cauchy property is all you can do. If you have a sequence $(x_n)_{n}$ corresponding to another $b$, then all you need to show is that $(a_n-x_n)_n$ is a zero sequence, as then both $(a_n)_n$ and $(x_n)_n$ have necessarily the same limit.

Comment: I can't prove that $(a_n-x_n)_n$ is a zero sequence right? The best I can show is that starting from some $N$ it will be.

Comment: With zero sequence I mean a sequence converging to zero. Otherwise even starting from some $N$ will not give a constantly-zero-sequence (in general).