# Convergence in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: profinite-groups

The following is part of an exercise from Lenstra's Galois theory for schemes..

Let $a=\frac{b}{c}\in \mathbf{Q}^\times$, $n\in \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^\times$.

Prove that there exists a sequence of positive integers $(n_i)_{i\geq 0}$ that satisfies $\operatorname{gcd}(n_i,2bc)=1$ for all $i$ and such that $n=\lim_{i\to\infty} n_i$ in $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$.

---

First of all, I have trouble understanding convergence of sequences in $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$. A similar exercise on convergence is treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858648/convergence-of-sequence-a-0-b-and-a-n1-2a-n-in-hat-mathbbz) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152861/convergence-in-z-hat-modulo-prime-power), but I don't seem to understand this.

Of course, taking the definition of convergence using the topology would give: $(a_n)$ converges (to $0$ for example) if and only if for every open set $U\ni 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $a_n\in U$. We can know use that an open neighbourhood is given by finite intersections of $Ker \pi_k$ and so on, but this seems so complicated..

A claim in solutions I found on the internet says the following: a sequence $(a_k)$ converges in $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ if and only if for all $n$, the sequence of reductions $(\pi_n(a_k))_{k\geq 1}$ in $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$. I don't see why this claim is true. (One direction is trivial, since the projections are continuous.)

Could someone give and explain thoroughly how we should attack proving convergence of sequences in $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ and give a hint for this exercise? I think we should use density of $\mathbf{Z}$ in $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$, but then I don't see how to incorporate the other conditions?

Answer (score 1):

"I don't see why this is true" : this is the definition of $\mathbf{\widehat{Z}=\varprojlim Z/mZ}$, the set of limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod m$ for all $m$. This proves that the $\gcd(n_i,bc)=1$ condition works iff $p | bc \implies n\not \equiv 0\bmod p$.

When restricting to $n\in \mathbf{\widehat{Z}}^\times$ this condition is satisfied.

Concretely let $ n_i$ such that $n \equiv n_i \bmod i!$ and $i > bc$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am afraid I don't see why this is the definition. The definition I know is $\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{ (x_n)_{n\geq 1} \in \prod_{m\geq 1} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \mid x_k=x_\ell \bmod{k}\text{ for all }k\leq \ell \}.$

Comment: This is the same ! From a convergent sequence you get yours by reducing the limits $\bmod$ each $m$, and from yours you get a convergent sequence from the reduction $\bmod$ each $ i!$

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand :( It would be great if you could elaborate the most possible

Comment: What ? Take any integer $n_i$ representing $x_{i!}\bmod i!$ then $\lim_{i\to \infty} n_i$ converges to $x$ in the profinite integers. The next step is to construct some profinite integers, for example the one which is $\equiv 1\bmod 2^k$ for all $k$ and $\equiv 0\bmod p^k$ for all odd prime.

Comment: But my whole point is: what does convergence in the profinite integers mean? I understand that: "From a convergent sequence you get yours by reducing the limits mod each " because projection is continuous. But " from yours you get a convergent sequence from the reduction mod each !"? Where does $i!$ come from? How do we know that we get a convergent sequence if we don't know what convergence means? You say : "by definition", but this isn't the definition right?

Comment: $i! $ is divisible by $m$ once $i$ is large enough, it is a factorial, the reduction $\bmod i!$ contains the information $\bmod m$ whenever $m\ |\ i!$